# Persist output of window function in db with Spark dataframe in java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When the following snippet executes:

```
Dataset<Row> ds1=ds.groupBy(functions.window(ds.col("datetime"),windowLength,slidingLength).as("datetime"),ds.col("symbol").as("Ticker"))
        .agg(functions.mean("volume").as("volume"),functions.mean("price").as("Price"),
        (functions.first("price").plus(functions.last("price")).divide(value)).as("Mid_Point"),
        functions.max("price").as("High"),functions.min("price").as("Low"),
        functions.first("price").as("Open"),functions.last("price").as("Close"))
        .sort(functions.asc("datetime"));

ds1.printSchema();
```

Output:

```
|-- datetime: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Ticker: string (nullable = true)
 |-- volume: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Mid_Point: double (nullable = true)
 |-- High: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Low: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Open: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Close: double (nullable = true)
```

Now when I am trying to save it into a csv file I am getting the error that csv file unable to resolve datetime as timestamp.

Error:

```
cannot resolve 'CAST(`datetime` AS TIMESTAMP)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast StructType(StructField(start,TimestampType,true), StructField(end,TimestampType,true)) to TimestampType
```

Someone has any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply datetime cast to the col rather than applying it to the sliding window,

```
ds.col("datetime").as("datetime")
```

Comment: datetime is not a cast type its a column name.
for casting I am using the following code:

ds.withColumn("datetime",ds.col("datetime").cast("timestamp"))